# Recover ETH with TXhash

Tags: ico, recovery

3 months ago I sent ETH to join Electroneum ICO.

My transference apparently arrived once the ICO had closed and my ETH remains locked in the chain.

The TxHash is 0x31e56ef1edcf32353157782cbdf4a06a731f571f3bd438c63f21ceeafc‌​f8ed7e

How can I send it back to my wallet?

Any help is useful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum transactions are permanent. If the transaction failed, then the ether never left your account. If the transaction succeeded, then the ether now belongs to the contract you sent it to.

If the contract is well-written, either it should have failed the transaction in the first place or it should provide a function to send the ether back to you.

If you provide the transaction hash, it may be possible for someone to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The TxHash is 0x31e56ef1edcf32353157782cbdf4a06a731f571f3bd438c63f21ceeafcf8ed7e
If someone knows how to recover it, please help!

Comment: That transaction went to a normal account, not a contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x04da0f0779aadec2871f0e48b82be3647a676a54. Only the owner of that account could send it back to you.

Comment: Is it possible to know who's the owner of the account? 
It is the address Electroneum gave me for the ICO so I assume it is theirs..
Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, there's no way to know who has the private key for that account. Have you contacted the people behind Electroneum?

Comment: Yes, several times... I got in touch with their support team but have not been able to give me a solution so far.. Also, every time you open a ticket with them takes them over 10 days to answer.. terrible support team..